# MYSQL UPDATE Table on INSERT into same table

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger, insert-update, mysql-error-1442

it seems simple, but still a challenge. I simplified my issue as much as possible.

I have this test_table with one record:

```
    id | cost_per_record
    1  | 24
```

After an INSERT I want the table to look like this:

```
    id | cost_per_record
    1  | 12
    2  | 12
```

From the application I work from I cannot CALL a STORED PROCEDURE so the code I used among others:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
    CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `cost_per_record` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES (1,24);

    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `test_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    update `test_table` set `cost_per_record` = 12 
    where `id`  = 1;
    END
    $$
    DELIMITER ;

    INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES
    (2,12);
```

The error I usually receive (also on other attempts):

```
    MySQL said: Documentation 

    #1442 - Can't update table 'kan_test_update' in stored function/trigger because it is already      used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Believe me, I read quite some answers on this forum and also ran into blogs saying this is [impossible](https://github.com/markkolich/blog/blob/master/content/entries/mysql-trigger-error-1442-hy000-cant-update-table-tbl-in-stored-functiontrigger-because-it-is-al.md). But I am (still) not accepting this. So.. any solution... thanks...

Comment: What happens with 2 or more records to start?  Your requirement is somewhat unusual.

Comment: 'But I am (still) not accepting this' - you should. BTW in a before insert trigger you can adjust the value of the NEW. column. please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for detail.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Perhaps an alternative design would suit your scenario better

Comment: As said I simplified my problem as much as possible, I just want to update other record(s) from the same table after or before an insert

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon I think I need a second table.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger like following only can change the current  inserted row.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.`id`  = 1 THEN
    SET NEW.`cost_per_record` = 12;
END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To update other rows and also insertiung, you can only use a stored procedure.

like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`( IN _id Integer, IN _Value INTEGER)
BEGIN
IF _id  >  1 THEN
    UPDATE test_table SET `cost_per_record` = 12 WHERE id = 1;
END IF;
     INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES
    (_id,_value);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `cost_per_record` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES (1,24);


call new_procedure(2,12);

SELECT * FROM test_table;
```

To insert new rows
Or you find another algorithm that can use triggers and so didn't involve the same table

[Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) have a lot of restrictions, so you should remeber that, when you try to make a new system

Comment: Thanks, but changing to that code gives this result in my table:

         id | cost_per_record

        1 | 24

2 | 12

Comment: bare in mind I add the Trigger after the first insert, the second insert should update the first record

Comment: @Frits Nagtegaal your last comment is not explained in your question and what's the logic for id 2 updating id one and what's the logic for the amount to set id 1 to?

Comment: @FritsNagtegaal i updated my answer, that is so not solvable, instead use a procedure

Comment: @nbk Thanks, but as stated in the request 'From the application I work from I cannot CALL a STORED PROCEDURE'. I can CALL a SP in the Trigger like you described, but that gives the same 1442 error. I think I need a second table

Comment: You have to use the procedure instead of the insert and also don't use a trigger see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

For me now underneath solution works, so using a second table. I added some intelligence, so adding a third record will reduce the cost from 12 -> 8. I use this to give discount for people ordering more meals from the same meal_group. Still this is a kind of workaround, and not the initial question, but hey. Thanks all, who replied.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sub_table`;
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `sub_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cost_per_record` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `sub_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES (1,24);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE `sub_table` set `cost_per_record` = (24/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_table`)) ;
INSERT INTO `sub_table` (`id`, `cost_per_record`) VALUES (NEW.ID,(24/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_table`)));
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`) VALUES (3);
SELECT * from `sub_table`;
```